# How to scroll a RichTextBox to the end of the text?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, scrollbar, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox on a Form.
I'm adding some text to the control in the Form.Load event.
When the Form is shown, I want the RichTextBox to scroll down to the last line of text.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Form.Load event handler, change the current insertion position to the length of the Text, setting the [TextBoxBase.SelectionStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart) property and use the [`ScrollToCaret()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.scrolltocaret) method to scroll to that position:

`ScrollToCaret()` may not be even needed (depending on the Framework version).

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.TextLength;
    // If the controls doesnt' scroll setting SelectionStart, add
    richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();  
}
```